# What kind of matrix transformation can be in this code?

Tags: math, matrix

What kind of matrix transformation can be in this code?

```
mat[3][0] += a0.y * mat[0][0] + a0.z * mat[1][0] + a0.x * mat[2][0];
mat[3][1] += a0.y * mat[0][1] + a0.z * mat[1][1] + a0.x * mat[2][1];
mat[3][2] += a0.y * mat[0][2] + a0.z * mat[1][2] + a0.x * mat[2][2];
```

Comment: This question is a bad fit for this site. Please give more context or explanation of how this is a programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `mat` is an affine transform represented in homogeneous coordinates, this is a post-translation by vector `t`, where `t = (a0.y, a0.z, a0.x)`:

```
/ m00  m01  m02  m03 \     / 1  0  0  a0y \
| m10  m11  m12  m13 |  *  | 0  1  0  a0z |
| m20  m21  m22  m23 |     | 0  0  1  a0x |
\  0    0    0    1  /     \ 0  0  0   1  /
```

The result of this expression is exactly what you have in code. (Note: Indexing in the above expression is inverted to yours in order to fit the traditional notation in math).